# Здравствуйте. Почему я получаю данную ошибку в первой строчке: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '45,6'

Tags: python

```
a = [int(input())]
b = []
for i in range(16):
    if len(a) == 2: #2 элемента - возраст и инвалидность
        b.append(a) #добавление в пустой список данных если есть значения возраста и иналидности
    if a[0] <= 55:
        a[0] = "Senior"
        i = a
    else:
        print("Age is not avialable")
        input()
    if a[1] <= 7:
        a[1] = "Open"
        i = a
else:
    print("Level of invaliding is not available")
    input()
```

Comment: Потому что в качестве разделителя числа с плавающей точкой должна использоваться точка, а не запятая. Хотя это было бы важно если бы вы использовали “float()”, int() по-моему не понимает ни точек ни запятых

Comment: `a = list(map(int(input().split(','))))` что-то такое вам надо, наверное. Но у вас дальше по коду всё-равно какой-то бред, извините